# Number of points of parabolic Springer fibres for general reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, reductive-groups

My question is the same as [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405066/number-of-points-of-parabolic-springer-fibres) but for an arbitrary reductive $G$ instead of just $\mathrm{GL}_n$.

Let $G$ be a connected split reductive group over a finite field $k$.
Let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup of $G$ and $u\in P$ a unipotent element. The parabolic Springer fibre associated to $(P,u)$ can be defined by
$$
\mathcal{P}_u:=\{gP\in G/P \mathrel\vert g^{-1}u g\in P\}\subseteq G/P. 
$$

Question: Is this variety pure? Is it polynomial count? If so, is an explicit formula  for the counting polynomial known?

For $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$ a complete answer is given in the above post.
In classical types, it is known that these varieties admit affine pavings; see for instance, [Fresse - Existence of affine pavings for varieties of partial flags associated to nilpotent elements](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405066/number-of-points-of-parabolic-springer-fibres).

Comment: Just to clarify, when you write the word "pure", are you asking about the weights of Frobenius on the etale cohomology or are you asking about dimension / heights of associated points ("pure" in the sense of EGA)?  Given your second question, I assume you mean weights of Frobenius.

Comment: I mean weights of the Frobenius. Thanks for the clarification.